# Why are some ISO numbers greyed out on my Canon 7D Mark II?

Tags: camera-settings, iso, canon-7d

I am only able to select ISO 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400, 12800, 16000. Everything else is greyed out. I can't find anything online about it. I find it hard to believe that I am the only one that has experienced this. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check advanced options to see if ISO step is in 1... if it is, change it to 1/2 or 1/3 as needed.

Comment: yes that fixed it!! post your this as an answer and let me select it as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check advanced options to see if ISO step is in 1... if it is, change it to 1/2 or 1/3 as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Canon 7D Mark II is a very configurable camera. One of the options the user has is to choose which options are selectable from various menus. ISO speed setting increments is one such choice.

On page 434 of the [EOS 7D Mark II Instruction Manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300016615/02/eos7d-mk2-im2-en.pdf) there are instructions on how to set *Custom Function 1 (C.Fn1: Exposure) --> ISO Speed Setting Increments* to either 1-stop or 1/3-stop increments.

[image: p.434]

Comment: It would be helpful to know what part of the answer is incorrect or how it might be improved if one is compelled to downvote, especially on such a straightforward answer.